# Prevent error text appearing in Mail Merge when there is no image to display

Tags: excel, mailmerge

I have a document that uses mail merge to display images that are retrieved as URLs from a spreadsheet pointing to the image and the code works well.

```
{ INCLUDEPICTURE "{ IF TRUE { MERGEFIELD my_photo_variable_name} }" \d }
```

The issue I have is that when there is no image URL for the current mail merge, an error message is displayed.

```
Error! Filename not specified.
```

I am trying to engineer the code so that it just leaves the mail merge field blank like it does for text fields rather than display the error message.

I tried tried using an `IF` clause to determine if there is an image:

```
{IF { INCLUDEPICTURE "{ IF TRUE { MERGEFIELD my_photo_variable_name} }" \d }}
```

but that didn't work so I tried using another `IF` clause determine if the variable was a null value (no image):

```
{IF {{MERGEFIELD my_photo_variable_name} <> ""}{ INCLUDEPICTURE "{ IF TRUE {{MERGEFIELD my_photo_variable_name}  " \d }}
```

Both of these attempts do not even show the error message let alone the image. Anyone know a way around this or am I stuck with an error message?

Comment: Possible near-duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20372870/word-2010-combining-includepicture-and-if

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was very close, incorrect curly bracket placement was what was causing my attempt to fail:

```
{IF {MERGEFIELD my_photo_variable_name} <> "" {INCLUDEPICTURE "{IF TRUE {MERGEFIELD my_photo_variable_name}}" \d} "Text to display if no picture available"}
```

Which translates as:

If there is no value for the image `my_photo_variable_name`, include the image in the mail merge.

If there is no value i.e no image, then display custom text `Text to display if no picture available`.